# Adding MailChimp CNAME records

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, ns-record

MailChimp asked to authenticate our domain by adding CNAME records. So far, Mailchimp seems to have authenticated the records, but when I do a NS query on the many NS checkers online, none of them could read my CNAME records (they could read my TXT records). How come? It's been 24 hours. I'm using CloudFlare, and I've already added the same CNAME records there.

https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx

https://www.nslookup.io/dns-checker/

https://dnschecker.org

https://manytools.org/network/query-dns-records-online

Comment: Start by giving the name involved and even the full record. There is nothing to wait (bad 24 hours DNS propagation myth...) if people query authoritative nameservers. Of course noone can do that since you are not giving out the details of your case..

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Sorry, I'm ready to give out the site names since Google can index this.

Comment: Imagine this: in one year, someone stumbles on your question because it has the exact same problem. Or so it seems. Can it compare his situation with yours, details per details? Certainly not as there are no details in your question. You just give generic links to 4 tools and say they do not work for your purpose without any detail. The purpose of this site is not only just to provide help but also to build a good Q/A collection for future uses. In that sense, I am not sure your question will help future users.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: Also imagine this: in one year, someone has the same problem. Instead of googling and finding this question he immediately asks a new one, like the majority here seems to do. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CNAME is set for the subdomain, not for the root domain, so if you want to query the CNAME you have to query the subdomain itself, for example: `k1._domainkey.example.com`.